# Unknown 414 GB Device / Partition / Volume in EC2 Linux Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volume, partition

For about 3 of my Amazon EC2 instances I noticed that each contains two 414GB partitions / devices.

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

> major minor  #blocks  name
>
> 202       65    6291456 xvde1
>
> **202      144  440366080 xvdj**
>
> **202      160  440366080 xvdk**

```
df -h
```

> Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/xvde1            5.7G  5.0G  605M  90% /
>
> none                  3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm
>
> /dev/xvdj             414G  276G  117G  71% /ebg
>
> /dev/xvdk             414G   14G  380G   4% /eby

```
fdisk -l
```

> Disk /dev/xvde1: 7516 MB, 7516192768 bytes
>
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 913 cylinders
>
> Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
>
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk identifier: 0x00000000

_

> Disk /dev/xvdj: 450.9 GB, 450934865920 bytes
>
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 54823 cylinders
>
> Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
>
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk identifier: 0x00000000

_

> Disk /dev/xvdk: 450.9 GB, 450934865920 bytes
>
> 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 54823 cylinders
>
> Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
>
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
> Disk identifier: 0x00000000

My Question is that I dont know where these partitions came from and I need to know how I can recreate them in other instances. I have not been able to create an instance with these partitions present.

Also since these partitions are not shown in the volumes section of my EC2 Dashboard I dont know what they are and how much I am being charged for it.

I will appreaciate any help I can get. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what does fdisk -l gives you and df -h command do they show /dev/xvdj and /dev/xvdk and also /dev/xvde1.

Comment: I have added the outputs to the question. How do I recreate a similar instance

Comment: Also might I mention that from my EC2 console I have similar instances that say root device is ebs and have the same instance ID's but one of the instances has only the root partition while the other has the extra 450GB drives. Im very confused here. How can I replicate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They appear to be instance store volumes. These are included in the price of the instance, but need to be explicitly enabled by the AMI or by you at launch.

While you can use instance store volumes to store data, they will get deleted if the instance is stopped or has failed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I recreate an instance with the same type of config. I want all my linux instances to benefit from these volumes. Can you also point out an exact AMI that contains these volumes and a short description of how to enable them at launch